# Running a classic ASP website on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation, windows

I will start the conversion of an old web site programmed on Classic ASP to PHP. I'd like to run and test the ASP scripts locally.

So, how can I run these ASP scripts in my Linux Ubuntu 12.04 (w/ LXDE) system?

I know I can use a VM in Virtual Box and install the stuff there. If this is the only solution, maybe I'll do that.

Perhaps someone will suggest something on Wine. I don't know.

But I would prefer if there is something that can run natively, as PHP itself runs... ideally I would configure my NginX HTTP server similarly as I do for the PHP files...

I wonder if such an installable Linux version of classic ASP exists... does it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know *back in the day* (and we're talking about fourteen years ago, when I was using ASP) there were alternative implementations of ASP. The most famous and the only one I've ever seen running on not-Windows was ChiliSoft ASP.

But ChiliSoft were gobbled up by Sun. Sun killed off ChiliSoft's product but imbibed its soul and capabilities into Sun Server One. More time occurred and Sun were eaten by Oracle... Somewhere in that time the product died. Even if it does somehow *exist* still, I would bet a large pot of money on it not being maintained, let alone compatible with Linux 2.6+.

### ASP is *ancient*.

I shouldn't need to point that out but I need to highlight that nobody has considered it worthy of promoting in over a decade, let alone waste a ton of time reimplementing such a horribly limited language and framework.

There may be the possibility of getting an alternative implementation running under Wine. Or even a native one - but if your legacy code uses anything like an ODBC database (kids these days won't have a clue what I'm talking about), you're going to be stuffed.

The easiest way to deal with this is to just mirror your stack from 10 years ago. Bung a copy of Win2k on Virtualbox, and just host it the way it was designed for. Do your porting and then *move* all the files onto a flash drive (or Iomega Zip Disk if you hate anachronisms), tape that to a heavy rock and then and drop that baby in the ocean.

---

**Note:** Packages like `Apache::ASP` are red herrings. There are plenty of modules that give ASP-like interpretation. `Apache::ASP` gives a Perlscript-like spin on the whole thing but it won't let you run VBScript.

**Note 2:** [ModVB exists](http://modvb.sourceforge.net/) but seemingly hasn't been touched since its inception in 2003. And that is based on [mod_gb](http://modgb.sourceforge.net/) from 2002 which has had similarly low activity in the past decade. I'm not sure either of these would work with a modern Apache and you've still got ancillary issues (eg databases) still.

**Note 3:** You *could* also reimplement ASP yourself with a home-made parser written in whatever language you like. Most languages that have been around a while have language parsers. It'd probably be slower and buggier but it might be enough to actually run something. But seriously, if you're even considering this, you're very silly. Please just reimplement your site in a current language.

Comment: Indeed, Virtual Box will be the way to go. Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: It should be noted that even if you found a way to run classic ASP/VBScript code on a Linux (e.g. Apache or nGinx) server, many legacy classic ASP applications are dependent on Windows COM+ objects such as CDONTS and other custom DLL's, which will not run in Linux. Virtualization is an option, but if you go that route, do *not* use an unsupported version of Windows server such as 2000 or 2003, as these suffer from unpatched security flaws that will expose your infrastructure to unnecessary attack.

Comment: SAVED BY THE BELL ---

So, here we are... four years later. You know what happened? I'll tell you: in the very same day I was going to sign this job's contract, I was offered a much better one, paying 4x more. It ended up that - lucky me - I never had to make this classic ASP to PHP conversion.

I still thank for the great answer, anyway.